# Razer Diamondback 3G cannot Left-Click after driver update

Tags: razer-mouse

I've been having this weird problem for months now after getting my Razer Diamondback. After I installed the drivers for the mouse, now my mouse cannot left click on boot up to Windows until I do an alt-ctrl-del. After that I can left click as normal. Anyone know what could possibly be causing that?

Answer (score 1):

I also Razer mouse owner. I've bought my Razer Diamondback (first generation) long time ago. They have very strange drivers so I decided never to use them.